# Login is not working in Spring MVC with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My login is not doing anything. I made a similar project and there it worked. The Register is working, but the Login button is not doing anything. Any ideas why is not working?

I'll put my DemoApplication, SecurityConfig and login.html down.

- login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href = '../css/login.css' rel = 'stylesheet'>
    <title> Login </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "panel">
    <form class="login-form"  th:action="@{/DS_login}" method="post">
    <input id = "loginButton" type="image" src="../img/b1.gif" name = "login" value="Login">
    <p> Login </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label> username </label>
    <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "username">
    <br>
    <label> password </label>
    <br>
    <input type = "password" name = "password">
    <br>
    <p id = "wrongLogin">Wrong credentials</p>
    </form>

    <p class="message">Not registered?  <a th:href = "@{/DS_Register}" href = "register.html">Register</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

-DemoApplication

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/DS_login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

-SecurityConfig

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/DS_Register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/DS_login").permitAll();

        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/DS_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/DS_Home",true);
    }
}
```

---- please help ----

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the type="image" as it is problematic because the ability to pass a value is disabled.

Use a button instead.

```
<button type="submit" name="someName" value="someValue"><img src="someImage.png" alt="SomeAlternateText"></button>
```

Comment: it is sending me at this link: http://localhost:8080/DS_login?error

Comment: And it is annoying because I've done it a lot of times before, and now it's not working.